# powershell error for AzureUSGovernment/GCCH Sentinel

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sentinel

I am trying to run a powershell script to deploy Azure Sentinel to a GCC high or AzureUSGovernment environment. Whenever I run the script, line 17 of my script returns an error. Below is line 17 of the script:

```
Set-AzSentinel -subscriptionid  $subscriptionId -WorkspaceName $workspaceName.Name -Confirm:$true
```

This is the error message for line 17:

```
"Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)."
```

What did I do wrong? This script works for commercial environment.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow:

- *It seems it would be a environment issue* ***Please Make sure that you have logged in to your **`Azure government portal`** through [***PowerShell***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-get-started-connect-with-ps) by selecting the correct account details with subscription*** .
- Please verify the limitation and availability for [**`MICROSFT SENITEL as mentioned here`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/compare-azure-government-global-azure#microsoft-sentinel) .

***NOTE:-***

> ***As [**Azure sentinel**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-sentinel-new-features-promotional-offer-for-free-ingestion-of-aws-cloudtrail-logs/) is generally available for Azure Government you can do the perform once you will connect with your
> account.***

*For more information please refer this* [**`GitHub`**](https://github.com/wortell/AZSentinel/blob/master/docs/Set-AzSentinel.md#outputs) docs.